# How do I test emails that have attachments in different clients?

Tags: email, testing, language-agnostic

Is there a way to test emails with an image attachment in different clients? (GMail, Hotmail, AOL Outlook, etc.)?

Comment: Shouldn't they all behave kinda the same way?

Comment: what do you want to test? whether an attachement is embedded or viewed as an attachment?

Comment: Send e-mail from your app to your various e-mail addresses, use a different client for each address. Is that what you're asking for? (I'm not sure)

Comment: @zneak: I'd say that's the point of the testing - there are various quirks, esp. where various web interfaces come into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you're after but [Litmus](http://litmus.com/) is great for testing emails in loads of different email clients.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test is by viewing the attachment in the different client. All these clients are subject to change so you should go to the source.